# how to count the array values with key

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this i need to count by array values

```
Array ( [Cop] => Array ( [0] => Dozen [1] => Dozen [2] => Akls [3] => Akls ) [MSN] => Array ( [0] => Dozen ) [NeK] => Array ( [0] => Suhan [1] => Ebao ) [NetSE] => Array ( [0] => SuZhan [1] => Guhang ) )
```

For example

```
 Array ( [Cop] => Array ( [0] => Dozen [1] => Dozen [2] => Akls [3] => Akls ))
```

In the Cop key i have two different values for cop so i need cop should be `2`

```
Cop - 2
MSn - 1
NeK - 2 
NetSE - 2
```

I need the count like above how can i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try simply using `array_map`,`count`,& `array_unique` like as

```
array_map(function($v) {
            return count(array_unique($v));
        }, $arr);
```

Comment: You cannot get a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Uchiha The alternatives? i guess the rest of the answers... but this is the most elegant one.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**array_unique()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and then count.

```
count(array_unique($array['Cop']));// output 2
```

If you want to print for every key do following:

```
$array = array('Cop'=>array('Dozen','Dozen','Akls','Akls'), 'MSN'=> array('Dozen'), 'NeK'=> array('Suhan','Ebao'));
foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value = count(array_unique($array[$key]));
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Cop = 2
MSN = 1
NeK = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use array_count_values() for that, here's an example:

```
$data = array('cop' => array(0 => 'test', 1 => 'test', 2 => 'test2'));

foreach($data as $item){
    $result = array_count_values($item);
    print_r($result);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 2
    [test2] => 1
)
```